# How to use lookup in mongoose if local field have array form value in single dimension?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, graphql

One field have value in single dimension. I want to use lookup that field to another document but getting only one record.

Here my user schema and org schema with aggregate query.
with data in user and org documents

```
users[
{
   _id:32442141dfdsaf2
    name: user1
 },
 {
   _id:42442141dfdsaf2
    name: user2
 },
]

orgs[
  {
   _id:87878978978
   name: org1
   userIds: array(ObjectId('32442141dfdsaf2'),ObjectId('42442141dfdsaf2'))
  }
]

db.orgs.aggregate([

{
        $lookup:
           {
             from: 'users',
             let: { assignedTo: '$userIds' },
             pipeline: [
               {
                 $match: {
                   $expr: {
                     $and: [
                       { $in: ['$_id', '$$assignedTo'] },
                     ],
                   },
                 },
               },
             ],
             as: 'users',
           },
      },
])
```

Comment: Please add sample db documents and query you re trying to run and expected result

Comment: Why not just use lookup without pipeline
 {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "users",
         localField: "userIds",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "users"
       }
  }

Comment: $lookup:{from: 'users',localField: 'assignedTo',foreignField: '_id',as: 'users'} used but give only one record.

Answer (score 0):

[If the localField is an array, you can match the array elements against a scalar foreignField without needing an $unwind stage.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#use-lookup-with-an-array)

```
db.orgs.aggregate([{
       $lookup:
       {
            from: "users",
            localField: "userIds",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "users"
       }
}])
```